# Django api backend filter table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The goal is to get the photos associated with a listing id.
I have the bellow structure in django rest framework

Model.py

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Listings, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    post_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    guid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_mime_type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pictures'
```

Serializer.py

```
class PicturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pictures
        fields = ('index', 'listing_id', 'guid')
```

Views.py

```
class PicturesListViewAlt(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PicturesSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request is None:
        return Pictures.objects.none()
    id_of_listing = self.kwargs['listing_id']
    return Pictures.objects.filter(listing_id=id_of_listing)
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'pics'

    urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^pictures/(?P<listing_id>.+)/$',
            views.PicturesListViewAlt.as_view()),
]
```

I keep getting the bellow errors.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column pictures.listing_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...ELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pictures.listing_id".

[03/Feb/2022 11:58:17] "GET /api/pictures/123/ HTTP/1.1" 500 24360
```

Although I have never initiated a column listing_id_id

And

```
    ProgrammingError at /api/pictures/123/
    column pictures.listing_id_id does not exist
    LINE 1: ...ELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "pictures" WHERE "pictures"...
                                                                 ^
    HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pictures.listing_id".

Which when I change my filter to pictures__listing_id I get 

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'pictures' into field. Choices are: guid, id, index, listing_id, listing_id_id, post_mime_type, post_title
[03/Feb/2022 12:07:46] "GET /api/pictures/123/ HTTP/1.1" 500 22236
```

Sorry for the long question but I have been at it for hours. Any help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Database Representation [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#database-representation)

> Behind the scenes, Django appends "_id" to the field name to create its database column name

That's the reason why it appends `_id` to your `listing_id` field and it searches for `listing_id_id` as column. So you don't have to add `_id` while declaring `Model`.

Change your `Picture` model as

```
class Pictures(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    index = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listings, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    post_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    guid = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_mime_type = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pictures'
```

Also change your `Serializer.py` as

```
class PicturesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pictures
        fields = ('index', 'listing', 'guid')
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Now I get: ProgrammingError at /api/pictures/
column pictures.id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "pictures"."id", "pictures"."index", "pictures"."list...

Comment: Because you don't have `primary_key=True` in your `Pictures` models and Django will look for the `id`  that Django gives each model. You can add `id` column as `primary_key=True` or make any column `primary_key=True` in your model. Do you have `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` in your `settings.py` ?